# Ensuring validity of an object pre- or at- construction

Tags: java, oop

I'm modeling a car which has a color.
I want to make sure the color is a valid one. So I created a nested enum inside the Car class that will hold the valid colors. I would like to understand this idea:

1. how should someone create a car?

   - expose the enum. and in the constructor expect an enum value. this ensures a valid color.
   - the enum is mine! the user of my class doesn't need to know about it! i will have him give me a string, which I will parse for any of the enum values. If it's not valid I will throw an exception

I'm more inclined with exposing. is there any reason I would not like to do this? for example, maybe over-complicating the user with creating an instance of a car? (though I guess he would prefer this over run-time exception).

what do you say?

Comment: What do you think of implementing the enum as a standalone class? It is currently only a feature of the car, but it might be used by other classes, too. And a color as such is not so car-ish...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the factory pattern. You can hide all the checks and color handling code there and your `Car` can remain as it is now (with `Color` as an enum parameter). The factory doesn't have the limitations of constructors and you are free to give names for your methods as you like, for example:

```
public class CarFactory{
   public static Car createRedCar() { return new Car(Color.RED);  }
   public static Car createBlueCar(){ return new Car(Color.BLUE); }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the relation of the question I asked, and the decision of whether to use a factory or not. But I will use this to launch another question: wouldn't I have an explosion of methods the way that you suggest? for each color of the car I need a method, and then for any other property of the car (number of wheels for example) giving me: createRedCarWith4Wheels(), createRedCarWith6Wheels(). I foresee you will tell me to use the builder pattern. But I still haven't understood how the builder is going to receive the parameters from me. maybe you can share with me if you do?

Comment: The factory object is only a helper. You can still create new Car using your constructor (with parameters such as color or number of wheels). The point is, that the creation of Car is separated from the Car itself into one place. If you'll have more parameters (number of wheels, type of engine,...) than abstract factory will be more suitable. The way how factory's parameters are bound to the car's constructor is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The factory solution it's nice and elegant, but forces you to add new methods every time you need to add a new color. And if you want to add something like "number of wheels", then you are in trouble, as you would double the number of factory methods. I would stick to the exposing solution. It's very easy to understand, gives you some flexibility (adding a new color it's as easy as adding one line to your enum class) and it's very Java's style. You know, Java it's very verbose! But it's just an opinion.

Comment: thanks for your input JavierV. how would you handle the case if the requirements specify that you need to have valid colors for car and motorcycle which can be different? create 2 enums (each in it's respective class) or a general enum?

Comment: Good question... Two enums would be fast and verbose, but you could choose to implement a general enum and a color "filter" ColorValidator(Enum colors). This way, you can have your generic enum with all colors, and specify the restriction for each class in a different "validator". The validator would be implemented as a static part of your car/motorcycle class and let you decide which colors are accepted for motorcycle and which ones for cars

Answer (score 0):

I think exposing the enum isn't a problem in this case. The method using strings isn't not very safe regarding valid values. Use the enum to explicitly define which values are valid. That's what enums are there for after all ;-)

You should also consider further usage of the car class. If you need to get the color of your car in another context, you also want to return the enum instead of a string, meaning you'd have to make it public anyways.

If think the factory pattern is not applicable in your case but it's hard to say without knowing the whole context your car class is used in.

Comment: I completely agree, that was my biased opinion before I came here. But Uwe Allner got a point, he is saying: you need color of car? but you have also a motorcycle whose valid colors are other. The solution that you (Andre) and I agree upon will create 2 color enums. he is suggesting to use a more general *1* enum for both cases. I don't know what is better. anyone knows what is better in that case?